# haskell sum type multiple declaration error

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types

```
data A=A
data B=B
data AB=A|B
```

Which makes a sum type AB from A and B.

but the last line induces a compile error "multiple declarations of B"

I also tried sth like this:

```
data A=Int|Bool
```

It compiles. but why ghc disallows me from making sum types for user-defined types?

Comment: Wow! This edit *completely* changed the details of the question, making all the answers look a bit stupid. That's not really the recommended way; instead, if you find you are still confused after your first question, open a fresh one with details about your new question, how it differs from the previous one, and why you're still confused.

Comment: sorry,the previous one is in fact a simplified one...and after some experiments i find it best to post the original one ,sorry..thanks for the detailed typing ! would you like to update your answer?

Comment: @doofin: no.. you should revert your edit and open a new question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting fooled. You think when you write `data A=Int|Bool` that you are saying that a value of type `A` can be a value of type `Int` or a value of type `Bool`; but what you are *actually* saying is that there are two new value-level constructors named `Int` and `Bool`, each containing no information at all, of type `A`. Similarly, you think that `data AB=A|B` says you can either be of type `A` or type `B`, but in fact you are saying you can either have *value* `A` or *value* `B`.

The key thing to keep in mind is that there are two namespaces, type-level and term-level, and that they are distinct.

Here is a simple example of how to do it right:

```
data A=A
data B=B
data AB=L A|R B
```

The last line declares two new term-level constructors, `L` and `R`. The `L` constructor carries a value of *type* `A`, while the `R` constructor carries a value of *type* `B`.

You might also like the `Either` type, defined as follows:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

You could use this to implement your `AB` if you wanted:

```
type AB = Either A B
```

Similarly, you could use `Either Int Bool` for your tagged union of `Int` and `Bool`.

Comment: Given that neither `A` nor `B` carry additional information, one could probably throw them away entirely and use `data AB = A | B`, but that's hard to see without additional code.

Comment: @Zeta I'm assuming that `data A=A` and `data B=B` were merely placeholders for more interesting data types.

Answer (score 1):

Because the type of the value created using data constructor `A` or `B` will be ambiguous. When I have `a = B` for instance, what is the type of `a`? It is `A` or `AB`?

You should consider using different data constructor as follows:

```
data A = MkA
data B = MkB
data AB = A A | B B
```

Comment: I guess you meant  `data AB = A A | B B`. After all, it should be a sum type of A and B.

Comment: Ah, right, thanks for the correction, was meaning to write that

Answer (score 1):

When you say `data AB = A | B`, you are not referring to the *types* `A` and `B`, but rather are defining *data constructors* `A` and `B`. These conflict with the constructors defined on the the previous lines.

If you want to create a type `AB` that is the sum of `A` and `B`, you must provide data constructors that wrap the types `A` and `B`, e.g.:

```
data AB = ABA A | ABB B
```

Answer (score 1):

Sum types have to be tagged. `a+a` has to have two *injections* from `a`.

To understand how algebraic data types work, take a simple example:

```
data X = A | B C
```

This defines a new type constructor, `X`, along with data constructors `A` and `B`. The `B` constructor takes/holds an argument of type C.

The primary canonical sum type in Haskell is `Either`:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```