# Using Haskell sum type to make recursive lists - recursion anchor?

Tags: haskell, recursion

Trying to understand Haskell better, I want to build some recursive list structures using sum types.

These two types are unrelated, but in the same file:

```
data EList = EList {elem::Point, rest::EList} | Empty
data ETree = ENode {val:: Int, left::ETree, right::ETree} | Empty
```

So I get a "multiple declarations of 'Empty'" error. Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541929/haskell-sum-type-multiple-declaration-error) post, I understand that 'Empty' is not a keyword (as I assumed when this data type was presented in class).

If I want to use n types like this in my program, I have to come up with n different names for the empty element, that doesn't seem right.

Is there a common expression to determine the end of the list?
Or should I just not be using this 'homemade' type?

Comment: why don't you just call the first 'Empty' - `Nil` and the second one `Leaf` ? then it would 'feel right'. But ultimately you have to - do this - otherwise `Empty` can be used to construct Trees or Lists - maybe some LANGUAGE extension can help you - i am thinking of `AllowAmbiguousTypes`, but i am not sure.

Comment: Another option is that - as they are unrelated - create two modules - MyList and MyTree -  then, as namespaces are per module, the problem is solved, if you then use both within one file you have to do qualified imports. Take a look at the [`containers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) package to see a neatly organised example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that you were allowed to declare two datatypes with an `Empty` constructor, as you have done. Given the definition

```
x = Empty
```

what would be the type of `x`? It could be `EList` or `ETree`, but the computer can't know which one you meant. That's why in general, you're can't declare the same name more than once in a given file.

One simple solution is simply to use different names. Here I'm using `Nil` for the empty list and `Leaf` for the empty tree, as is conventional.

```
data List = Cons Point List | Nil
data Tree = Node Int Tree Tree | Leaf
```

(Aside: It's usually not a good idea to declare record fields in a sum type because it means the extractors will be partial functions.)

An alternative is to put your two overlapping names in different files.

List.hs:

```
module List where
data List = Cons Point List | Empty
```

Tree.hs:

```
module Tree where
data Tree = Node Int Tree Tree | Empty
```

Now, if you import both of these modules, referring to `Empty` is disallowed because once again the machine doesn't know which one you meant. But this time, you can sort it out yourself using qualified names.

```
import List
import Tree

emptyList = List.Empty
emptyTree = Tree.Empty
```

Comment: This is a correct answer, but I can't help but point out that the computer would be able to cope with the `x = Empty` definition if the language required type declarations for ambiguous definitions like this one. Haskell already does this for numeric literals. So it's a language-imposed rule, not some law of nature.

Comment: @LuisCasillas I agree, and indeed some languages are more flexible than Haskell about overlapping names of different types; Haskell chooses to prioritise type inference instead. Numeric literals aren't quite the same thing, though; they're polymorphic, with a type of `Num n => n`, so the type is chosen using Haskell's normal instance selection rules.